# Is it possible to change the background color of a single cell in ParseQueryAdapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, parse-platform

I have been trying to visually indicate the state of a single element in the list generated by ParseQueryAdapter but the code below changes the background color of multiple rows.

Have tried to log whenever the setBackgroudColor is called and this seems correct, so it must be due to android reusing the view I guess.

```
@Override
public View getItemView(final ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (v == null) {
        v = View.inflate(getContext(),
                R.layout.view_circuitunit_adapter_item, null);
    }

    super.getItemView(object, v, parent);


    final CircuitUnitStarted circuitUnitStarted = (CircuitUnitStarted) object;


    if (circuitUnitStarted.getTimeEnded() != null) {
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    }

    return v;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solutions seems to always color either white or grey:

```
if (circuitUnitStarted.getTimeEnded() != null) {
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
} else {
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

Do not know why I did not think of that before